# RemoveAt() not working c#

Tags: c#, list, removeclass, removeall

Even after the `RemoveAt()` method, my list keeps being the same and I don't even get an error:

```
foreach (var row in queryCandidates.ToList())
{
    try
    {
        xString = queryCandidates.ToList().ElementAt(i).District;
        int.TryParse(xString, out xNumber);

        temp = xNumber.Equals(districtNumber);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(temp+ " ");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(i+" ");
        if (temp == false)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" i is:"+i);

            //not working even when it should
            queryCandidates.ToList().RemoveAt(i);

        }
    }

    catch { }
    i++;
    if (last == i)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("before ending loop: ");
        return View(queryCandidates.ToList());
    }
}

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("after ending the loop: ");
return View(queryCandidates.ToList());
```

Comment: That's a lot of `ToList()`'ing there.

Comment: Everytime you  create a new list(`queryCandidates.ToList().RemoveAt(i);`), remove an item from it and  throw away the list

Comment: The empty `catch{}` will only hide errors. Better to remove it.

Answer (score 7):

`ToList()` creates a new instance. From this instance you are removing the element. You are *not* removing the element from the original enumerable.

You should be doing something like this instead:

```
var candidates = queryCandidates.ToList();
var elementsToRemove = new List<int>();
foreach (var row in candidates)
{
    // ...
    xString = candidates[i].District;
    // ...
    if (temp == false)
    {             
        // ... 
        elementsToRemove.Add(i);
    }  
}

for(int i = elementsToRemove.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    candidates.RemoveAt(elementsToRemove[i]);

return View(candidates);
```

Please note the use of `elementsToRemove`. You can't remove the items directly in the loop. This will throw an exception.

---

Additionally, please note that `ToList` copies all data. Every single time you call it. It should be obvious that this is not a good idea to do in a loop.

Comment: Another problem is that he/she is trying to modify a collection in a foreach loop. This will not work.

Comment: @downvoter: Please leave a comment so I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
queryCandidates.ToList().RemoveAt(i);
```

ToList() creates a brand new list, which you then remove an element from, but that list is long gone.

Try:

```
var newList = queryCandidates.ToList();

for (int i=newList.Count-1; i>=0; i--){
 ///snip
 newList.RemoveAt(i);
```

Note that I changed your foreach to for (in reverse) because you cannot modify a list while you are iterating over it with foreach.

Answer (score 3):

The ToList() function creates a new List every time you call it. The object is removed from that list, not from the original list. So you should call ToList once before the foreach.

Once you've done that the removeAt() call will work and cause new issues because then you are trying to modify the list from within the foreach loop. So you'll need to rewrite your code in a way which takes the remove out of the loop as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not exactly sure what Type queryCandidates is, but the reason you are not seeing an update is because you are removing element 'i' from the wrong object. Your ToList() function creates a new object of List type. If you want to keep the change you need to cache that list and use it where you use your original queryCandidates object.

Comment: Ok thank you for your quick answers, and also for making me notice why it wasn't being saved the result

Comment: No problem, but please note that C# can get very angry if you try to modify a list that you are iterating over. So you will probably have to change your foreach loop to either a while loop (check if i < length) and only increment 'i' if you are keeping the element, or cache the indexes of elements to remove, and remove them all outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

`queryCandidates` isn't a list.

You're converting it to a list which creates a new instance from which you're removing the item but doesn't affect `queryCandidates` itself.

You can do:

`var queryCandidates myCollection.ToList();`

and then

`queryCandidates.RemoveAt(i);`

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to remove from the bottom up:

```
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    if (list[i][0] == "&nbsp;" || list[i][3] == "0")
        list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

It makes sense that some items are missed after decreasing the item count.